# Seeing posts next to each other

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a django blog and I'd like to know if there's something that can make me see posts next to each other instead of one under another like the image:

[image]

Here's the css code:

```
 <style>
        body {
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            background-image: url("{% static 'img/periodic_table.jpg' %}");
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
       
        }


        div.container {
            align-items: center !important;
            text-align: center !important;
        }


        .navbar-default {
            background-color: transparent !important;
            border-color: transparent !important;
        }

        p{
            color: white;
        }

        .wrap-login100 {
            margin-top: 70px;
            background: #fff;
            border-radius: 10px;
            min-height: 20vh;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 15px;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;;
        }
        
        h3 {
            padding-top: 20px
        }


    </style>
```

And here's the template:

```
{% load static %}


<html>
{% include 'periodic/head_search.html' %}
<body>
    {% include 'periodic/header.html' %}
<br>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Latest Posts -->
      <main class="posts-listing col-lg-8 "> 
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <!-- post -->
            {% for element in query %}
            <div class="col-6">
              <div class="wrap-login100 p-l-110 p-r-110 p-t-62 p-b-33 post">
                <div class="post-thumbnail">
                  <a href="{{ element.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{ element.thumbnail.url }}" alt="..." class="img-fluid"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="post-details">
                </div>
                <a href="{{ element.get_absolute_url }}">
                  <h3 class="h4"> {{ element.title }}</h3>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
{% include 'periodic/scripts_search.html' %}
</html>
```

I know this isn't exacly a thread, but I'd like to know whether there's some css code that can fix so that I can learn a bit more of html and css

Comment: On your post wrapper div which starts with the class `wrap-login100` try to use the class `col-3` instead of `col-xl-6` and remove the second `col-xl-6` because it's unnecessary.  You can also reduce the left and right paddings `p-l-110, p-r-110` from 110 to a lower value.

Comment: Also, we can't see how your other classes `wrap-login100, six, wide, post` affect the grid. One of them might be forcing the column to use 100% of the width. Try to remove these classes one by one from the wrapper div and see what happens.

Comment: Now you can see the other css classes. Give it a look if you want

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, I am using Bootstrap

Comment: Can you remove the `post` class from this div `<div class="wrap-login100 p-l-110 p-r-110 p-t-62 p-b-33 post">` and see what happens?

Comment: Can you show a live link or HTML code without dynamic code because the provided code is not enough

Comment: Ok problem solved. I used the float: left and it has worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using Bootstrap, I recommend keeping "col" classes separate from your custom CSS which could affect the default layout in Bootstrap. Using just only "col" class will keep your posts side by side. You can make them responsive by adding necessary device-related classes.

```html
<div class="row ">
  <!-- post -->
  {% for element in query %}
  <div class="col">
    <div class="wrap-login100 p-l-110 p-r-110 p-t-62 p-b-33 six wide post post">
      <div class="post-thumbnail">
        <a href="{{ element.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{ element.thumbnail.url }}" alt="..." class="img-fluid"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="post-details">
      </div>
      <a href="{{ element.get_absolute_url }}">
        <h3 class="h4"> {{ element.title }}</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried what you told me and it still doesn't work. Do you have any more suggestions?